# why linux remote command or bash script does not return correct output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, remote-server

I am facing issue while executing a remote command. If I execute command by logging into remote machine, it works. But if I execute same command from my laptop to remote machine it returns different status code.

```
Local execution on 192.168.0.166:  
root@monica-E470:~# virsh list --state-shutoff | grep Qcow2 | wc -l
1

Remote Command execution: 
root@sandipd-ThinkPad-E450:~# ssh root@192.168.0.166 'virsh list --state-shutoff | grep Qcow2 | wc -l'
root@192.168.0.166's password: 
0
```

I have tried with different scenarios, but no luck. Has anyone faced same issue?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong there, but what about `ssh root@192.168.0.166 virsh list --state=shutoff | grep -Fc Qcow2`? (Replacing `grep | wc -l` with `grep -c` is just an optimization, not really the beef here -- the main thing is to run the `grep` locally, as there is no reason to run it as `root` on the remote server.)

Comment: (... unless the output is humongous and you would like to avoid sending it over the remote pipe.)

Comment: Still not working. -c option will not help. After execution of remote command it always return 0.

Comment: What if you remove the pipeline, or change it to just `| cat`? I'm guessing there will be no output from `virsh list` but I have no idea why.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `virsh` but are there any environment variables set in the local session that are not there when you ssh? You can compare with the output of `env` in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a pseudo terminal to execute complex commands in a remote server. Try this instead:

```
ssh -t root@192.168.0.166 'virsh list --state-shutoff | grep Qcow2 | wc -l'
```

Refer `man` page of `ssh` for more info.

Comment: Cool man. Its working. Yes will check this pseudo terminal thing.